# The meaning of $\{a,b]$, Munkres Topology . Is it a typo?

Tags: general-topology

In the book of *General Topology* by Munkres, at page 100, question 5, it is asked to prove that in general the inequality

$$Cl(a,b) = \overline{(a,b)} \subseteq \{a,b]$$

holds. However, I don't know what that he means by $\{a,b]$ ? Is it just a typo ? and does he mean $[a,b]$ ?

Comment: I've found a partial errata for this book ( https://www.math.toronto.edu/drorbn/classes/0405/Topology/etc/MunkresErrata.html ).  Surely there's a full errata somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should be $[a,b]$. Possibly depending on the edition and printing, the book does say $[a,b]$. And that's the only thing that makes any sense in the context.

Comment: If you have an electronic copy that is saying $[a,b]$, it would be nice if you could share it. I mean my copy might have some other typos too.

Comment: That's a fair request, but I'd rather not engage in piracy quite so publicly! Let's just say it's not that hard to find.

Comment: ChrisCulter, how about a screenshot?